# Data-table server-side pagination with laravel query limit

Tags: php, laravel-4, datatable, server-side

I am using below query for random number of row in laravel.

```
Select * from table order by rand() limit 0,1000
```

And my data-table pagination size is 100 but pagination doesn't working properly when i am using limit in query.

How can i implement this using above query in laravel with server side pagination ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to make pagination after querying the results, because Laravel add limit automatically. Add below code to your model:

```
public function getPaginatorResults($pagination) {
    $total = $this->getTotal();
    $query = $this->orderByRaw('rand()')
                  ->skip($pagination * (\Paginator::getCurrentPage() - 1))
                  ->take($pagination);
    $results = $query->get();

    return \Paginator::make($results->all(), $total, $pagination);
}
```

Comment: How can i use this function because i am using data table ajax part using laravel and laravel making response using $query->make(true) like that.

Comment: Past the whole code of the model (if there is), controller and routing because I can't tell you where you have to put it.